# ERROR SQL MYSQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

al general esta sentencia:

```
ALTER TABLE `usuario_rol`  ADD  FOREIGN KEY (usuario) REFERENCES
usuarios(id)
```

me devuelve este error en Mysql:
#1005 - No puedo crear tabla `utiles`.`usuario_rol` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

¿Sabéis porque se produce?

Comment: ¿Ninguna de las [preguntas del sitio](/search?q=Error%3A+150+%22Foreign+key+constraint+is+incorrectly+formed) están relacionadas a la tuya?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que partes de una estructura similar a la de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
  id int,
  usuario varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE usuario_rol(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  usuario int
  );
```

Y, al intentar añadir una clave ajena con la instrucción:

```
ALTER TABLE `usuario_rol`
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (usuario) REFERENCES usuarios(id);
```

Recibes el error:

> Can't create table `_so`.`usuario_rol` (errno: 150 "Foreign key
> constraint is incorrectly formed")

El error se produce porque MySQL no permite referenciar un campo como clave ajena si previamente no ha sido al menos indexado. Evitarías el error con un simple:

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios
  ADD INDEX(id);
```

Pero mejor te recomiendo que, además de indexado, tu campo sea clave principal y auto-incremental. Para lo que puedes usar la instrucción:

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios
  MODIFY id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: Lo conseguí arreglar, reparando la bbdd mysql de mysql., muchas gracias!!